# Javascript onChange checkBox

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok guys so I am hopelessly new to Javascript. I have been doing good so far. But I can't seem to figure out what the issue is here. I am trying to send some data to a php file via GET to change some data on the database when you check the checkbox. Here's the code.

```
<?
$comple = $tasking['status'];
if($comple=="complete"){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<? echo $tasking['id']; ?>" checked="true"
onchange="change()"> <? echo $tasking['detail']; ?><br>
<?
}
else{
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<? echo $tasking['id']; ?>" onchange="change()"> <? echo 
$tasking['detail']; ?><br>
<?
}
?>



<script>
function change(){
var id = document.getElementById(this).name;
var ch = document.getElementById(this).checked;
var sendto = 'changetask.php?id=' + id + '&&ch=' + ch;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
else{
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: And whats your problem.? Is there any error.?I dont see a question here.

Comment: If you are facing issue in sending request to php page then i suggest instead of using javascript based ajax use jquery.

Comment: There isn't an error. Basically I thought I knew what I was doing and then it didn't work. I showed the code I used. But I am just trying to get it to change some database data with this code and changetask.php

Comment: Honestly I couldn't tell you the difference between ajax and jquery. I don't know javascript very well. I just recently started picking up on it 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Demo : http://jsbin.com/obiFisIL/1/edit

ur `html` code should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<? echo $tasking['id']; ?>" checked="true"
onchange="change(this)"> <? echo $tasking['detail']; ?>
```

In ur html I added "this" in `onchange` function as parameter.....

ur `js` should be

```
function change(dis){
var id = dis.name;
var ch = dis.checked;
-----
```

Full code

```
<?
$comple = $tasking['status'];
if($comple=="complete"){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<? echo $tasking['id']; ?>" checked="true"
onchange="change(this)"> <? echo $tasking['detail']; ?><br>
<?
}
else{
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<? echo $tasking['id']; ?>" onchange="change(this)"> <? echo 
$tasking['detail']; ?><br>
<?
}
?>



<script>
function change(dis){
var id = dis.name;
var ch = dis.checked;
var sendto = 'changetask.php?id=' + id + '&&ch=' + ch;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
else{
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: Not me. I can't add or take away. Not signed in.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a Redundant parentheses at the end is that the problem ??? Otherwise the code is fine.

```
<?
$comple = $tasking['status'];
if($comple=="complete"){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<? echo $tasking['id']; ?>" checked="true"
onchange="change()"> <? echo $tasking['detail']; ?><br>
<?
}
else{
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<? echo $tasking['id']; ?>" onchange="change()"> <? echo 
$tasking['detail']; ?><br>
<?
}
?>
```

Here is modified code..

Comment: The } closes the 'else'. Yeah I changed it to that. I am staring at this code. I wonder if its the rest of the javascript I might have done wrong.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I do see that extra } in my code.. Not yours. But there is a lot of code that isn't shown. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm sorry for that being an issue for you. It is my first time ever using this site.